# Recursive method is not working in main, how come?

Tags: java, recursion

I was wondering why does recursive method Question(); does not run in main? The error method in Eclipse says "The method Question(int) is not applicable for arguments ()". Doesn't my method Question() make the argument (int)? Sorry if this is confusing, I will keep a hawk's eye on this board and assist with any questions regarding my program for clarification.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program9Recursion {

    //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void Question(int n) {
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
        n = in.nextInt();
        
        if ( n>= 1 && n <=10) {
        System.out.println("You inuptted " + n);
        
        }else {  
            System.out.println("Please correctly enter a number between 1 and 10:");
            n = in.nextInt();
            Question(n);
        }
    }
        
        
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
    Question();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, for clarification, the purpose of this method is to make a recursive method, where the user inputs a number and it has to be between 1 and 10, if it is not between 1 and 10, recursion enacts and should ask the user to re input a number between 1 and 10.

Comment: The answer is contained in the error message.  In your `main` you call `Question();` with no arguments because there's nothing between the parentheses.  The method is declared to take one argument of type `int`.  Mismatch.

Comment: Hi pjs thanks for your response, shouldn't my Question() method call the argument?

Comment: You should pass an argument to the method, as in `Question(10);`, or `int n = 42; Question(n);`.  In other words, you're required to give that method an integer value whenever you call it, and you didn't do so in your main.

Comment: It worked :) thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;

public class Program9Recursion {

```
//Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void Question(int n) {
    
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    if ( n>= 1 && n <=10) {
    System.out.println("You inuptted " + n);
    }
    else {   
        System.out.println("Please correctly enter a number between 1 and 10:");
        n = in.nextInt();
        Question(n);
    }

}
    
    
    
public static void main(String[] args) {                
Question(11);
}
```

}